# Django Model and blog author permisson problem

Tags: django

I am trying to build a Django blog and the problem is, when a new user registered, it does not appear in add blog section until it is add in the blog as blog author.

Here is my model:

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class Author(models.Model):
    name = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    profile_picture = models.FileField()
    detail = models.TextField()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name.username

class Category(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class Article(models.Model):
    author = models.ForeignKey(Author, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    body = models.TextField()
    image = models.FileField()
    posted_on = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=False, auto_now_add=True)
    updated_on = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True, auto_now_add=False)
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category, on_delete=models.CASCADE)


    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

I am showing my admin here:

[image]

and this is my article posting form:

[image]

I need when a user registered and logged in the register only appear in name section (3rd Screenshot)

Even the problem is, in name section, it asks me to register a user as blog author name, but i dont need this. I need all the registered user should go in article name section and only they can post if they logged in

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that when people register, they create a new `User`, *not* a new `Author`. The best way to get around this is to make `Author` an *extension* of `User` via a `OneToOneField`. For simplicity sake, let's rename `Author` to `UserProfile`, and automatically generate a `UserProfile` for a `User` whenever the profile is accessed. This means you can write `user.userprofile` to get all of the extra information about a user.

Here's an example:

```
class UserProfile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='userprofileAsUser')  # TODO: Use models.PROTECT... can't currently bc User.userprofile generates it again when trying to delete User
    profile_picture = models.FileField()
    detail = models.TextField()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name.username

def get_or_create_profile(user):
    profile, created = UserProfile.objects.get_or_create(user=user)
    return profile

User.userprofile = property(get_or_create_profile)


class Category(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name


class Article(models.Model):
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    body = models.TextField()
    image = models.FileField()
    posted_on = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=False, auto_now_add=True)
    updated_on = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True, auto_now_add=False)
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category, on_delete=models.CASCADE)


    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```